# Why the opencv's library on linux is libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a but libopencv_core.a?

Tags: linux, opencv

I always use opencv on windows.Now  I have a project on linux using opencv library. I notice that the static library of opencv  on linux is different with those on windows. On linux, all the library is named with such a string, _pch_dephelp. For example, libopencv_pch_dephelp.a rather than libopencv_core_version.lib(such as libopencv_core249.lib). Does the _pch_dephelp have some special meaning?

Answer (score 3):

`*_pch_dephelp.a` files are auxiliary libraries for precompiled headers support. You shouldn't use them in your application.

Real libraries for OpenCV modules on Linux are:

- `libopencv_core.a`, `libopencv_imgproc.a`, etc. - if you built OpenCV as static libraries;
- `libopencv_core.so`, `libopencv_imgproc.so`, etc. - if you built OpenCV as shared libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know the static library should be libopencv_core.a. But, after the build using cmake, only libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a is found in the lib folder. Where is the libopencv_core.a?

Comment: It seems like compilation failed. Please check make output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure cmake to build static libraries.

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?